# Edit Squashfs filesystem in flash memory

Tags: linux, memory-dump, flash, binwalk

I have read Flash memory and analyze with `binwalk` and find out Squashfs that I can extract with `dd` and open with `unsquashfs` .

When I open this FS I want to add some file into this FS and edit some shell script then pack this squashfs again and put it back into flash system.

The problem is :when I pack again the squashfs it bigger then the original fs. Then I can't put it exactly in the location into flash memory because it's overlap the next partition in FS.

What can I do please?